# PageCreate on Refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

ok, new to jquery mobile for a college assignment

im using ajax calls to pull in data from an external cms. as it stands im using the ajax call to dynamically insert the buttons for the homescreen and to create and link to the relevant pages for these buttons.... my problem is when I refresh the a subpage eg qualifications it automatically brings me back home... i have a #home.trigger(pagecreate) within the ajax call as otherwise my buttons wouldn't render as proper buttons instead of just links...

i presume that on refresh of a subpage the whole index.html is refreshed and therefore the pagecreate is triggered again...bringing me home...but the url is still pointing to #qualifications... if i navigate to another section of the app, and hit the back button (data-rel="back") it attempts to return me to the #qualifications page even though the last page displayed was the homepage... and ends up rendering no page at all....

how might i set up a function to catch the refresh... navigate back to the previous page (from browser history) and pagecreate the correct page...?

my apologies if the question is convoluted... first time posting! and technically im meant to be the graphics guys on the project... :)

Overall im attempting to use the ajax calls to dynamically build the whole site...

var nextpage[] being used to create the url ajax calls for the next level down in the cms... any smarter way?

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "http://myurl/api/list",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
            {

                var homepage=$('<div id="home" data-role="page" data-title="myguide : Home" data-theme="b">'
                    +'<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">'
                    +'<h1>Home</h1></div>'
                    +'<div id="logo">'
                    +'<img src="images/iiiguide_logo.png"/></div>');


                    homepage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                    $.mobile.changePage( homepage );

                    var pages=[];
                    var nextpage=[];
                    $.each(data.data,function(key,val)
                    {
                            var homebuttons=['<a href="#'+ val.label.replace(/\s/g, "")
                            +'" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"'
                            +'data-iconpos="right">'+val.label+'</a>'];
                            $('#home').append(homebuttons);



                            var pages=$('<div id="'+ val.label.replace(/\s/g, "") + '"'
                            +'data-role="page" data-title="myguide :'+val.label.replace(/\s/g, "") + '" data-theme="b">'
                            +'<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">'
                            +'<a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a>'
                            +'<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" >Back</a>'
                            +'<h1>'+ val.label.replace(/\s/g, "") +'</h1></div>'
                            +'<div id="logo">'
                            +'<img src="images/iiiguide_logo.png"/></div></div>');
                            pages.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);                          

                            nextpage.push('http://myurl/api/list?category_id='+val.id);

                    });


                    $('#home').trigger("pagecreate");                


            }

        }

 });
```

Comment: Have a look at this [Q&A](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html) from the documentation. As a side point the method you want to be triggering is `create` instead of `pagecreate`.

Comment: thanks for reply... i amended the code to create instead of page create. in the end i hardcoded the home div and will just inject the buttons from there and the resulting pages into the pagecontainer... refresh still brings me back to the homescreen but its a small annoyance, probably more a personal one then a users.